# Simplest way to compare column against a value that may (or not) be null

Tags: sql, sqlite, node-sqlite3

I have a prepared **SQLite** statement...

```
SELECT * FROM a WHERE col1 = $someValue
```

But when `someValue` is `null` the query returns no rows, so I wrote this...

```
SELECT *
FROM a
WHERE (
    col1 = $someValue OR
    (
        $someValue IS NULL AND
        col1 IS NULL
    )
)
```

This query works perfectly regardless of `someValue` being `null` or not, but it's very verbose. **Is there a simpler or more succinct way of achieving the same?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [Operators, and Parse-Affecting Attributes](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html#operators_and_parse_affecting_attributes):

> The IS and IS NOT operators work like = and != except when one or both
> of the operands are NULL. In this case, if both operands are NULL,
> then the IS operator evaluates to 1 (true) and the IS NOT operator
> evaluates to 0 (false). If one operand is NULL and the other is not,
> then the IS operator evaluates to 0 (false) and the IS NOT operator is
> 1 (true). It is not possible for an IS or IS NOT expression to
> evaluate to NULL.

You can use the operator `IS` to compare non-null values as well:

```
SELECT * FROM a WHERE col1 IS $someValue;
```

Comment: Of course, I should've thought of that :)

Answer (score 0):

If you would be using **postgres** there was `is distinct from` and I guess they have it because many feel with you:

```
SELECT * FROM a WHERE col1 is not distinct from $someValue
```

With **sqlite** it should be possible to write:

```
SELECT * FROM a WHERE col1 is $someValue OR col1 = $someValue
```

That is probably as short as it gets.

Answer (score 0):

Not as elegant as forpas's answer, but another alternative worth mentioning:

```
SELECT * FROM a WHERE ifnull(col1, 'x') = ifnull($someValue, 'x')
```

where the second parameter passed to the `ifnull` function, in this case `x`, is a value not already in the database and `col1` and `$someValue` are varchar columns.

Comment: If both parameters passed to `ifnull` are `null` then the query won't behave as expected. `ifnull(null, null)` returns `null` so it needs to be compared with `IS` rather than `=`.